# git mergetool --follow?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-log

is there a flag for `git-mergetool` that behaves like `--follow` from `git-log`?

```
   --follow
       Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only
       for a single file).
```

Basically I want it to merge renamed files instead of thinking they are deleted.

`git-mergetool` provides the following:

```
       When git mergetool is invoked with this tool (either through the -t
       or --tool option or the merge.tool configuration variable) the
       configured command line will be invoked with $BASE set to the name
       of a temporary file containing the common base for the merge, if
       available; $LOCAL set to the name of a temporary file containing
       the contents of the file on the current branch; $REMOTE set to the
       name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file to be
       merged, and $MERGED set to the name of the file to which the merge
       tool should write the result of the merge resolution.
```

So what I want, in the case of a renamed/moved file, is for BASE/LOCAL/REMOTE to still work.  I want `git-mergetool` to "follow" the rename of BASE to LOCAL or REMOTE, as appropriate.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to completely change it. Instead ask a new question. I've rolled this back to the version before the total change.

Answer (score 1):

`git mergetool` doesn't itself perform merges, only helps in cleaning up conflicts due to an merge that is already in progress. So it wouldn't make sense for that option to apply to the mergetool command.

It also doesn't make sense to have that option for `git merge`. Merging will always take file moves into account. The `--follow` option is only needed for the `git log` command to override a different behavior. As the bit that you quoted indicates that option only applies when getting the logs for a single file, in which case you've indicated that you're only interested in that specific file. The `--follow` option can be used to indicate that you also want information about previous names for that file.

Comment: doesn't `mergetool` gather the base file, the local file, and the remote file?  in this case, i'm asking that it actually gather those three instead of saying the remote file has been deleted when it has been moved locally.

Comment: No. `merge` places the different versions into the index.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear about what I want.  It has nothing to do with how different versions are stored, only that they exist.

Comment: This still doesn't change that `merge` **already follows renames**, so there is no use for a `--follow` option to either that or the `mergetool` command.

Comment: Okay, okay, I think I understand better what's going on here.  The rename isn't always being detected properly, so I guess I want a way to tell either `merge` or `mergetool` what LOCAL matches what REMOTE.